# After a few seconds, one turtle stops and the other goes faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

After weeks of trying, I have not come up with a solution to this issue, in which one turtle comes to a complete stop and the other goes 2x - 3x faster. How can I fix this? You must move them both around for a little bit to encounter the issue. Also this is on the site: repl.it

I have tried moving the `wn.listen()` command but that only switched which turtle stopped and which one didn't. I have unsuccessfully tried to switch the `forward()` command to `goto()` and I have tried to use direction specific movement (also unsuccessfully):

```
import turtle
import sys
player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.up()
player1.goto(0,350)
player1.right(90)
player1.down()
player2 = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

#preGame setup
player2.up()
player2.goto(0,-350)
player2.left(90)
player2.down()
player2.color("blue")
player1.color("red")
#main game loop
player1.speed(0)
player2.speed(0)
k = 0

def kr():
  player1.left(90)
def kl():
  player1.right(90)
wn.onkey(kr, "d")
wn.onkey(kl, "a")
def k1():
  player2.right(90)
def k2(): 
  player2.left(90)   
wn.onkey(k1, "k")
wn.onkey(k2, "l")

wn.listen()

while True:
  player1.forward(1)
  player2.forward(1)
  while player1.xcor() < (-350) or player1.xcor() > (350) or player1.ycor() > (350) or  player1.ycor() < (-350):
   player1.back(30)
  while player2.xcor() < (-350) or player2.xcor() > (350) or player2.ycor() > (350) or player2.ycor() < (-350):
   player2.back(30)
   if player1.pos() == player2.pos():
     print ("DONT CRASH INTO THE OTHER PLAYER")
     sys.exit()
```

I expected them both to continue moving indefinitely, but one always stops, and the other is going 2x the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Move the keylisteners outside your loop - having them inside the while loop will reattach them and redefine the functions all the time and confuse turtle.

You need to set them up *once* not every few milliseconds:

```
import turtle
player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.goto(350, 0)
player2.goto(-350, 0)
player1.right(180)
wn = turtle.Screen()
def kl():
    player1.left(90)
def kr():
    player1.right(90)
def k1():
    player2.right(90)
def k2():
    player2.left(90)
wn.onkey(kl, "d")  # changed to lowercase
wn.onkey(kr, "a")
wn.onkey(k1, "j")  # changed to other letters
wn.onkey(k2, "l")

wn.listen()

while True: # not changing k so just use while True
    player1.forward(1)  # changed speed
    player2.forward(1)
```

Comment: I have changed my code to the one that i am having a problem with hope that it makes a difference

Comment: @xu I have no idea what you are trying. This logic at the end is flawed though:  `if player1.xcor() < (-350) ` you should not go farther back but forward. else you get even more negative. Back and Forwards depend of the direction the turtle is looking - its probably better to set its postion absolute: if < 350 set it to 350 if > 350 set it to 350.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `while` loop structure is working against you and isn't valid for an event-driven environment like turtle.  Here's a rework of your program to fix this issue and clean up the code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import sys

# preGame setup

player1 = Turtle()
player1.hideturtle()
player1.up()
player1.goto(0, 350)
player1.down()
player1.right(90)
player1.color('red')
player1.speed('fastest')
player1.showturtle()

def r1():
    player1.left(90)

def l1():
    player1.right(90)

player2 = Turtle()
player2.hideturtle()
player2.up()
player2.goto(0, -350)
player2.down()
player2.left(90)
player2.color('blue')
player2.speed('fastest')
player2.showturtle()

def r2():
    player2.right(90)

def l2():
    player2.left(90)

# main game loop

def move():
    player1.forward(5)

    if not (-350 < player1.xcor() < 350 and -350 < player1.ycor() < 350):
        player1.backward(30)

    player2.forward(5)

    if not (-350 < player2.xcor() < 350 and -350 < player2.ycor() < 350):
        player2.backward(30)

    if player1.distance(player2) < 5:
        print("DON'T CRASH INTO THE OTHER PLAYER!")
        sys.exit()

    screen.ontimer(move, 100)

screen = Screen()

screen.onkey(r1, 'd')
screen.onkey(l1, 'a')
screen.onkey(r2, 'k')
screen.onkey(l2, 'l')

screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

See if this behaves more like you expect/desire.